# Looking to convert amount in numeric form to words?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Looking to convert amount in numeric form to  words? example if have amount as 600$ then in words i want to echo as six hundred Us dollars

Comment: Create a php session or javascript cookie when user log in and on your page welcome.php check if session or cookie is present or not if not then redirect page to login page. But also dont forget to destroy the created session or cookie when user log out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you log into a website, the information about your user account is typically stored in a session. That session is not shared across multiple browsers, it is stored in only that one browser. In your welcome.php file you need to check that the user is logged in before displaying information. If the user is logged in, proceed as normally, otherwise handle it somehow (I've seen redirections to the login screen, messaging saying that page can't be accessed, etc.).

This [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) will get you started with php sessions.

Comment: no but still it opens in other browsers

Comment: i have added this to every page pl see my edit

Answer (score 1):

Your php is wrong. This is what you need. In your code, the other browsers skip first one as SESSION['LAST_REQUEST_TIME'] is not set and sets a session without login

Try:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_REQUEST_TIME'])) {
    if (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_REQUEST_TIME'] > 180) {
        // session timed out, last request is longer than 3 minutes ago
        unset($_SESSION);
        session_destroy();
        header("location:to_some_login_page.php");
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['LAST_REQUEST_TIME'] = time();
    }
}
else {
    header("location:to_some_login_page.php");
}
```